# How to remove buttons and add a custom button on text selection bar in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want when we select a text then the text section bar appear. I want to remove all that buttons which comes in that bar like copy paste or cut and many more. I want to add my custom button so how can do this please help

[image]

As you see in this image I want to add a custom button on that and remove all these copy cut or replace buttons

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is the UIMenuController that appears when you select text in iOS apps.
To replace the default menu items with a custom one, follow these steps:

- Subclass the view responsible for showing the text (e.g., UITextField, UITextView).
- Override the canPerformAction method to prevent the default menu items from being shown:

  ```
   override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
   if action == #selector(customAction) { // Replace 'customAction' with your action's name.
       return true
   }
   return false
  ```

}